# como inserto un dato en una tabla relacionada en codigo php

Tags: php

necesito pasar el mismo valor para identificar que usuario ingresa cada columna, No hacer un select con inner join, si no pasar los datos.
tengo dos tablas

```
- tabla rusa (id_usu auto incrementable pk, usuario, password, checkbox)
- tabla contenido (id_con auto incrementable pk, negocio, slogan, id_rusa fk)
```

necesito que las tablas tomen los valores:

```
- id_usu id_rusa
-   1         1
-   2      2
-   1      1
```

ejemplo:

```
- id_usu,  usuario, password 
-   1,     juan,  4578 
- id_con   negocio    slogan     id_rusa
-   10,    carnitas ,  la mejor   ,   1
-   11 ,   barbacoa  , sabrosa    ,   1
```

---

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $negocio = $_POST['negocio'];
    $slogan = $_POST['slogan'];
    $imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $web = $_POST['web'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];



    $errores = '';

    if (empty($negocio)) {
        $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
    } else {
        try {
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=anunciate', 'root', '');


        $sql = 'INSERT INTO contenido (negocio, slogan, imagen, ubicacion, web, telefono) 
                VALUES (:negocio, :slogan, :imagen, :ubicacion, :web, :telefono)';
        $res=$conexion->prepare($sql);

        $res->execute(array(
            ':negocio' => $negocio,
            ':slogan' => $slogan,
            ':imagen' => $imagen,
            ':ubicacion' => $ubicacion,
            ':web' => $web,
            ':telefono' => $telefono,
            'id_rusa' => $row));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

  }
}
    require 'views/contenido.view.php';

?>
```

Comment: haz intentado con la funcion [mysql insert_id](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: no, como lo podria hacer ?